# Error sending a JSON via Axios post request in React

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to send a Json Data received from Formik. Data should look like this, and does look like this when console.log on Before sending:

```
{   config: {
       "dev_token": "merrr",
       "scs_date": "2020-02-05",
       "user_roll": "homie"
       }
}
```

However when I console log my req.body in Nodejs, I get this:

```
{
  config: '{\n' +
    '  "dev_token": "merrr",\n' +
    '  "scs_date": "2020-02-05",\n' +
    '  "user_roll": "homie"\n' +
    '}'
}
```

Why do I get the data without \n' attached? Any idea how to fix this?
The Axios request I made looks like this:

```
 Axios.post("http://localhost:8080/pd/sources/configure/"+this.state.ModalisName,{ "config" :config })
                                     .then(result => {
                                         console.log("PUT result", result)
                                     })
                                     .catch(err =>{
                                          console.log( "PUT err", err);
                                      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was caused by `JSON.stringify()` which I passed in before send the data over. Removed it and everything works well.